# How to use tf_remap?

Tags: ros, rosbag, remapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a rosbag in which a /tf topic is recorded.

I need to remap all tf frames in that bag which refer to the frame named '/world' to refer to a new frame named '/vision'.
I tried the following but it is unfortunately not working:

```
rosrun tf tf_remap _mappings:='[{old: /world, new: /vision}]'
```

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**:
I have also tried to do it from a launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="tf" type="tf_remap" name="tf_remapper" output="screen">
    <rosparam param="mappings">
      - {old: "/world",
         new: "/vision"}
    </rosparam>
  </node>
</launch>
```

but it's not working :(

Could it be that I am missing some argument when calling rosbag play?

**EDIT 2**: After searching, I found people saying that, in addition to running the tf_remap node, rosbag should be run as follows:

```
rosbag play x.bag /tf:=/tf_old
```

I tried it, and still it's not working :(

The tf_frames are still referring to /world rather than /vision.

Any help would be highly appreciated!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216582/how-to-use-tf_remap??/) by [beginner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22256/beginner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2015-08-26

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-02-04**:
Did you end up figuring this out? I would love to know the answer. Thanks!

**Comment by [OzzieTheHead](https://answers.ros.org/users/13406/ozziethehead/) on 2021-08-20**:
I know this is not what you are asking but, for this use case I would just find&replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I had the same problem and I found the following syntax to work from my launch file:

```
<node pkg="tf" type="tf_remap" name="tf_remapper" output="screen">
  <rosparam param="mappings">
    [{old: depth_camera, new: /camera_rgb_optical_frame},{old: thermal_camera, new: /camera_optris_frame}]
  </rosparam>
</node>
    
<node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="player" args="--clock $(arg bag_dir)/$(arg file)">
  <remap from="tf" to="tf_old" />
</node>
```

Bear in mind I was remapping two frames, so you probably won't need the comma. Also, my original frames didn't have a forward slash in front of them which is why I left it out.

You should then see a message printed to the console with something like the following:

```
Applying the following mappings to incoming tf frame ids {'depth_camera': '/camera_rgb_optical_frame', 'thermal_camera': '/camera_optris_frame'}
```

---

Originally posted by [Stephen Vidas](https://answers.ros.org/users/3606/stephen-vidas/) with karma: 131 on 2016-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [engyasin](https://answers.ros.org/users/36088/engyasin/) on 2018-09-03**:
and no qutation marks..

**Comment by [dj95](https://answers.ros.org/users/51703/dj95/) on 2020-05-07**:
Can tf_remap be used without using bag files?

**Comment by [Remi_Tortue](https://answers.ros.org/users/114193/remi_tortue/) on 2023-07-12**:
@dj95 Yes it can